# Connection timed out installing openni_kinect on electric

Tags: kinect, openni, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following the [wiki tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_kinect) regarding setting up openni_kinect on electric ubuntu 10.04

I am up to step 2.2 with the ubuntu installation and have tried
`hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers`
and I get the error
`abort: error: Connection timed out`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194033/connection-timed-out-installing-openni_kinect-on-electric/) by [zemark](https://answers.ros.org/users/20369/zemark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-02**:
kforge.ros.org has been down for a long time now. Also, Fuerte is EOL.

Do you have any particular reason for choosing those versions specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Ubuntu installation (2.1) and the source-based installation (2.2) are mutually exclusive - you should only do one.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-02**:
I've updated the wiki page to reflect this.